# Internal file auto delete?

Tags: android

My app copies the external captured pics to internal memory.Later or immediately the file is uploaded to server in online world. There are certain cases when the file to be uploaded is not present leading to FileNotFoundException. 78% of the cases has occurred in Xiaomi devices.

Is this because of any memory cleaner app ? Or any permission associated ?
Even a indicative idea of possible issue will be appreciated.

```
Non-fatal Exception: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file at path: /data/user/0/in.oku.brofirst/files/1497511679961.jpg
   at in.oku.brofirst.services.uploadservice.core.UploadFile.<init>(SourceFile:37)
   at awm.a(SourceFile:78)
   at awm.a(SourceFile:145)
   at awf.a(SourceFile:87)
   at awf.a(SourceFile:116)
   at in.oku.brofirst.services.uploadservice.util.NetworkChangeReceiver.onReceive(SourceFile:45)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2732)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1800(ActivityThread.java:153)
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1428)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5438)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:738)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:628)
```

Transfer file method

```
  public File transferFile(File file) {
    FileOutputStream fos = null;
    FileChannel inChannel = null;
    FileChannel outChannel = null;
    try {
        File transferredFileTo = new File(file.getName());// have the original name as the name in internal memory
        inChannel = new FileInputStream(file).getChannel();
        fos = context.openFileOutput(transferredFileTo.getName(), MODE_PRIVATE);
        outChannel = fos.getChannel();
        inChannel.transferTo(0, inChannel.size(), outChannel);
        return transferredFileTo;
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Crashlytics.logException(e);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Crashlytics.logException(e);
    } finally {
        try {
            if (inChannel != null && fos != null) {
                inChannel.close();
                fos.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Crashlytics.logException(e);
        } finally {
            //ultimately delete the file from gallery
            deleteLatestFile();
            deleteFileFromTempFolder(file);
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Crashlytics

[image]

Comment: it might be helpful you posted some code

Comment: Please edit your question and provide a [mcve]. This would include a sample Java stack trace for your `FileNotFoundException`, the code that leads to this exception, and the code that "copies the external captured pics to internal memory".

Comment: Commonsware - Please look at this